# Highlight table data based on list mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple list item and table data as per my snippet code. I want to highlight the `td` when mouse-over based on my list. Currently I did for only one list manually. I want to highlight every `td` based on list selection.

```js
$('.list1').mouseenter(function(){
   $('.listdiv1').addClass('bg');
}).mouseleave(function() {
   $('.listdiv1').removeClass('bg');
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

td {
  border:1px solid;
}

.bg {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="list1">List 1</li>
<li class="list2">List 2</li>
<li class="list3">List 3</li>
<li class="list4">List 4</li>
</ul>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="listdiv1">List 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="list2">List 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="list3">List 3</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="list4">List 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this.

```js
$('.dblmenu li').mouseenter(function(){
    debugger;
    var clsNm =$(this).attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1);
   $('td.'+clsNm+'div').addClass('bg');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    debugger;
    var clsNm =$(this).attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1);
   $('td.'+clsNm+'div').removeClass('bg');
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

td {
  border:1px solid;
}

.bg {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dblmenu">
<li class="accepted list1">List 1</li>
<li class="list2">List 2</li>
<li class="list3">List 3</li>
<li class="list4">List 4</li>
</ul>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="list1div">List 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="list2div">List 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="list3div">List 3</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="list4div">List 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can't get that. where you changed the position?

Comment: can you update your snippet in the question. with what you are trying?

Comment: I have noticed a `div` is attached to the class name as `list1div` in your site. I updated my snippet. check now

Comment: can you add debugger. inside mouse over in your website?

Comment: How can add the debugger. I am bit low in jquery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194860/discussion-between-dontdownvote-and-saravana).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var listItems = $('ul li');

$.each( listItems , function() {
   $(this).mouseenter(function(){
      varclassSelected = $(this).attr('class');
      $('table tr td').each(function (index, value) {
            var matchClass = $(this).attr('class');
            if (matchClass === varclassSelected) {
                $(this).addClass('bg');
            }
        });
   }).mouseleave(function(){
       $('table tr td').removeClass('bg');
   })
});
```

```css
ul li:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
}
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

td {
  border:1px solid;
}

.bg {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="list1">List 1</li>
<li class="list2">List 2</li>
<li class="list3">List 3</li>
<li class="list4">List 4</li>
</ul>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="list1">List 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="list2">List 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="list3">List 3</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="list4">List 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Please have a look, solution to your problem.

Comment: @Saravana  try using this

Answer (score 0):

Does this fix your problem by adding :hover on tr:

```css
table {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

td {
  border:1px solid;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.bg {
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li class="list1">List 1</li>
<li class="list2">List 2</li>
<li class="list3">List 3</li>
<li class="list4">List 4</li>
</ul>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="listdiv1">List 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="list2">List 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="list3">List 3</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>None</td>
    <td class="list4">List 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not working. I want to add the background when hover the list only.